# Android: how to add Icon at the left side of the TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to add icon at the left side of the textView.How can I do that?

Comment: have you searched for `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can do this using this code.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is there a way to center it?

Comment: @AlexeyShevelyov To center the text, you can use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in the layout file or `textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);` in the Java file.

Comment: and to add nice padding: `textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
                        context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.small_padding)` where R.dimen.small_padding - 16dp

Answer (score 150):

You can use:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

and you can also put padding between `drawable` and `textview` by

```
android:drawablePadding="2dp"
```

If you always want an icon to appear before the text, it is recommended to use `drawableStart` instead of `drawableLeft` since many languages are not read left to right.

Comment: How to change color of the icon when adding it via `drawableLeft`?

Comment: For API 17 and above Replace android:drawableLeft with android:drawableStart to support RTL

Comment: how about if gravity text is center , the icon didnt change into center following the text ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use this in your XML file:

```
android:drawableLeft
```

For your `TextView` and specify a drawable there your want to present on the left side of it.